# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net35

Tags: c#, .net, json

My code throws this runtime exception

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net35,
>   Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json.Net35, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}

But I have installed Newtonsoft.Json using NuGet

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of the Newtonsoft.Json library do you have installed?

Comment: try to add it in references then restart VS and run again.

Comment: @UweKeim `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed`

Comment: So this answers your own question, right? `4.5.0.0` seems to be different than `4.0.2.0`, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few options:

- Make sure nuget updated your packages.config file and packagerestore is turned on.  These can cause issues when using a VCS and a user doesn't properly commit changes back.
- Try restarting VS, I have found that after pulling down from a VCS, the references don't always update properly
- Open nuget, remove the package and reinstall it.